# jquery mobile custom icon repeats

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I must be missing something simple, but I can't seem to get a custom icon working. When I specify the data-icon attribute in my HTML link with corresponding CSS, the icon repeats as if other jQuery styling is being ignored. Not sure what I am missing, I did review the documentation for custom icons - looked pretty straightforward

Any help with be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding you have a separate class for each your icon.
You should set `background-repeat: no-repeat` for that custom classes.

Or unite it - example for fb icon:

```
background: url("fb18.png") no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I misunderstood how to use custom icons.